# Error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel' when using simply vpython

Tags: python, vpython

I'm just starting to try and use vpython, hoping to eventually use it to simulate an elliptical or parabolic orbit. I downloaded the module and tried to generate a simple sphere, and when I do so I get the above error. As far as I can tell, I have defined/called the function correctly. Here is my code

```
from vpython import *
Sun = sphere(pos=(0,0,0), radius =0.5))
```

Comment: might you need from vpython.visual import * --- i'm just took a quick look at: http://vpython.org/contents/bounce_example.html

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make a difference

Comment: the object `get_ipython` is null in `get_ipython().comm_manager.register_target('glow', GlowWidget)` of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 442`, I didn't know why the object was null recently.

Answer (score 2):

**vpython** is designed to run inside an IPython notebook (which is an interactive Python environment with a graphical interface used through a browser - think of it as a more powerful graphical python console).

When you used vpython in the normal Python REPL, the `get_ipython()` function returns `None` resulting in the error.

The easiest way to get IPython is to install Jupyter as described here http://jupyter.org/. Then launch it with `jupyter notebook` which will open a browser page where you can write the code and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially numerous ways to install vpython. Depending on your operating system. Graphical installation of vpython on Mac and Windows systems is straightforward (as well as how to run the installed executable). I will explain how to install vpython on Ubuntu 16. I will assume you already have python installed. 1.) vpython is dependent on PIP (a package manager for installing .py packages). So first use command **sudo apt install python-pip** to install the python-pip package with admin privilege. 2.) Once pip is installed from command line use pip to install vpython with this command: **sudo pip install vpython** (also using admin privs'). Make sure to upgrade pip to its most recent version using command: **sudo pip install --upgrade pip** 3.) The next steps entail the solution to either of the errors ('*NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'*) and/or (*No module named visual*) thrown by python or IDLE when trying to execute either command **from vpython import *** or **from visual import *** using python or within IDLE. The error is thrown because vpython is no ordinary .py package (containing a typical class or function statements), but vpython is a script that installs an **essential package known as jupyter-notebook** (with "y" and "-"). The jupyter-notebook package is what will actually interpret your vpython created .py files. 4.) Type the command **jupyter-notebook** into a terminal. This script will cause the terminal to provide a locally accessible address that you will enter into a web browser that supports Javascript and is also dependent on WebGL browser plugin support. 5.) Next as per the instructions provided at vpython.org, you will need to select the "New" drop-down list (found near the top-right of the jupyter browser page) and click "Vpython" option under notebooks. 6.) At the given prompt type your python commands as you would do with python interpreter or IDLE.

Answer (score -2):

It seems the name of the module is "visual", not "vpython".

Try this :

```
from visual import *
Sun = sphere(pos=(0,0,0), radius=0.5))
```

http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs_vp5/visual/VPython_Intro.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this earlier I got "ImportError: No module named 'visual'"

Comment: Well, then, sorry, I can't help further. I do not know "visual" module enough. I would say that if it doesn't import, it means that you do not have installed the correct module. But I supposed you already thought about that. Maybe if you tell us what you did to install  visual, step by step, we may help.

Comment: "ImportError: No module named visual"